# Convert Java object list to correct name value pair format in Json using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a Java Class named User with

```
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
@NotNull
@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;
```

I am trying to get some details in a list and convert it into JSOn like so:

```
Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
String queryString="select id,name from User where unit=:name";
Query query= sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(queryString);
query.setParameter("name", name);
List<User> users= (List<User>) query.list();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
Map<String, List<User>> wrap = new HashMap<>();
wrap.put("users", users);  // wrap user list in a map
String json = gson.toJson(wrap);
```

This produces a JSON

```
{
 "users": [
 [
  1,
  "Room"
],
[
  2,
  "Regi"
 ],
 ]
}
```

How do I change it so that I get a JSON like

```
{
 "users": [
 [
   "id":1,
   "name":"Rovom"
 ],
 [
   "id":2,
   "name":"Regi"
 ],
]
}
```

Edit
I realized it is the query that is causing the issue. If i use

```
String queryString="from User where unit=:name";
```

It gives the correct format. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you forced to use gson? I was just thinking that jackson for instance would probably do it right directly

Comment: oh - and your "expected result" still is not right - should be "users": [ {"id": 1, "name": Rovom"}, { ... as it's a list ob objects, not a list of arrays

Comment: @Jan no I am not forced to use Gson. Can you post the solution using Jackson.

Comment: Issue is not reproducible. Can you please update the question with complete `User` class or even better a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by user @Turo this is because of type erasure at runtime.

To fix this, the query has to be changed to

```
String queryString="select id,name from User where unit=:name";
Query query= sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(queryString).addScalar("name", new StringType()).addScalar("id", new IntType()).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class));

query.setParameter("name", name);
```

the addScalar() will map the values to the **User** objects and this gives the required result.

Answer (score 1):

Whith jackson, it'll look like this:

```
   String json = new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueToString(wrap);
```

You'd want jackson-core and jackson-databind for this at least.

Full example using Jackson:

```
public static class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public User(long i, String n) {
        id = i;
        name = n;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    try {
        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("users",  Arrays.asList(new User(1, "Stack"), new User(2, "Overflow")));
        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                .writeValueAsString(map));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

produced this output:

```
{
  "users" : [ {
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Stack"
  }, {
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "Overflow"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same output. Is it possible there is a binding issue between the object and the query?

Comment: can you share full object code for User then please?

Comment: I have edited the question. It is related to the query. Please check. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hm, looks like type erasure at runtime.

Your `List<User>` is with the first query actually a `List<Object[]>` as which it got serialized. Would you try to access an User-object out of the list, you'd get a runtime error, I suppose.

See hibernate documentation:

> Return the query results as a List. If the query contains multiple
> results pre row, the results are returned in an instance of Object[].

EDIT

to get a list of Users with only the two fields filled, create the apropriate constructur and use a query like

```
select new package.path.to.class.User(id,name) from User where unit=:name"
```

Comment: You might be on to something here. The getName() etc gives errors as well

Comment: @MontySwanson actually, i'm quite sure ;-)

Comment: So whats the fix?

Comment: The right query is the fix. With the original query `List<User> users= (List<User>) query.list();` is clearly wrong, only the compiler can't detect it.If yout Issue is, that User has many more fields you don't want in the JSON, you have to tell us...

Comment: Yes it has other fields. Name, ID, department, address etc. Some of them are references to other classes